# Similar pandas statement of SQL where clause

Tags: python, sql, pandas, where-clause

Two tables:
Price list table PRICE_LIST:

```
ITEM   PRICE
MANGO    5
BANANA   2
APPLE    2.5
ORANGE   1.5
```

Records of sale REC_SALE (list of transactions)

```
ITEM   SELLLING_PRICE
MANGO    4
MANGO    3
BANANA   2
BANANA   1
ORANGE   0.5
ORANGE   4
```

Selecting records from REC_SALE where Items were sold less than the PRICE listed in the PRICE_LIST table

```
SELECT A.*
FROM
(
    select RS.ITEM,RS.SELLING_PRICE, PL.PRICE AS ACTUAL_PRICE
    from REC_SALE RS,
         PRICE_LIST PL
    where RS.ITEM = PL.ITEM
) A
WHERE A.SELLING_PRICE < A.ACTUAL_PRICE ;
```

Result:

```
ITEM  SELLING_PRICE  PRICE
MANGO    4             5
MANGO    3             5
BANANA   1             2
ORANGE   0.5          1.5
```

I have these same two tables as dataframe in jupyter notebook
what would be a equivalent python statement of the SQL statement above using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge` with `.loc`

```
df1.merge(df2).loc[lambda x : x.PRICE>x.SELLLING_PRICE]
Out[198]: 
     ITEM  PRICE  SELLLING_PRICE
0   MANGO    5.0             4.0
1   MANGO    5.0             3.0
3  BANANA    2.0             1.0
4  ORANGE    1.5             0.5
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:

KeyError: 'the label [<function <lambda> at 0x0000000007EB1B38>] is not in the [index]'

Comment: How about `s=df1.merge(df2);s[s['PRICE']>s['SELLLING_PRICE']]`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ITEM').query('PRICE >SELLLING_PRICE')
print (df)
     ITEM  PRICE  SELLLING_PRICE
0   MANGO    5.0             4.0
1   MANGO    5.0             3.0
3  BANANA    2.0             1.0
4  ORANGE    1.5             0.5
```